# I alphabetize a large number of two-letter words. What is the expected ratio of words starting with A to words starting with B?

Tags: probability, limits, puzzle

I store my journal papers in a folder, ordered alphabetically by the name of the first author. Assume that each paper has two authors, ordered alphabetically. Assume also that each author name is generated randomly, so that given any letter of the alphabet, there is a 1/26 chance that an author's name starts with that letter (we generate the authors' names first independently, and then order them alphabetically).

Let $A^*$ be the number of papers in my folder where the first author's name starts with the letter A, and $B^*$ be the number of papers in my folder where the first author's name starts with the letter B.

> As the number of papers I put in my folder tends to infinity, what is
>   the expected value of the ratio $A^*:B^*$?

One may also ask, if we define $C^*, D^*,E^*$ analogously, what is the ratio $A^*:B^*:C^*:\ldots:Z^*$?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, in order to be in the $A$ folder, we require that at least one author's name start with $A$, yes?  If so, then the probability of that is $1-\left(\frac {25}{26}\right)^2$ .  Can you continue along these lines?

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to generalize if we take a direct approach.  For at least one name to start with $A$ the possible forms are $A*,*A, AA$ where $*$ is below $A$ in the alphabet.  The first two have the same probability, namely $\frac 1{26}\times \frac {25}{26}$.  The third has probability $\left( \frac {1}{26}\right)^2$.